# Intercepting web browser console messages

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a web app that's going to be rolling out to a few users for testing. There's obviously going to be bugs, so I'd like to capture them to make it easier to develop fixes. Is there a way for me to intercept any console messages (both browser/js errors and messages generated with console.log) in my web app, so I can send them to a logging service on the server and have them available for debugging?

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

Intercepting `console.log()` calls:

```
console['log'] = function(msg){
    // do wahtever you need with msg here
}
```

Intercepting errors (so called *diaper* anti-pattern):

```
try {
    // your app's code
} catch(err) {
    // do what you to do in case of error need here
}
```

Here is the proof: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TCYkf/).

However, I would suggest creating your own function, that will handle `console.log()` purpose and could be switched off on production. Plus, it will work properly (that means: won't throw errors), when the browser does not support `console.log()` calls. This could look like that:

```
window['log'] = function(msg){
    if (typeof console != 'undefined' && typeof console.log != 'undefined'){
        console.log(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Any tips on how to get this work for IE7 also? I just added the last snippet you provide in your answer, but console is still undefined in IE7.

Answer (score 1):

A little late... this may be an interesting read, just need to implement the method to send to the server, but that's trivial. [Taking Over console.log](http://tobyho.com/2012/07/27/taking-over-console-log/)