# Creating a custom "console" object to interact with Web Console in browser for custom debugger

Tags: javascript, debugging, firebug, google-chrome-devtools

The Mozilla Developer Network [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/console) on the browser-provided Javascript `console` object says: "`Note: At least in Firefox, if a page defines a console object, that object overrides the one built into Firefox.`". Is there any way to overwrite this object, but still interact with the browser's [Web Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console)?

A use case is to intercept `console.log()` calls and do something extra or take different parameters, such as a log classification, while retaining the line number/file information provided when logging to console by tools like Firebug or Google Chrome Inspect Element. The closest matching answer I could find is: [Intercepting web browser console messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6834981/interecepting-web-browser-console-messages), but it doesn't dive into interacting with the web console through a custom console object, and using a custom defined debug service like

```
debug.log = function(string, logLevel) {
    checkLogLevel(logLevel); // return false if environment log setting is below logLevel 
    var changedString = manipulate(string); 
    console.log(changedString); 
}
```

doesn't retain the line number/file source of the function calling `debug.log()`. An option is to do something with `console.trace()` and crawl one level up the trace stack, but I was curious about extending `console.log()` first. I'd also like to find a solution that works with existing Web Consoles/tools like Firebug rather than creating a custom browser extension or Firebug plugin, but if anybody knows of existing solutions for this I'd be interested in them.

Obviously something like:

```
    console = {
        log: function (string) {
            console.log('hey!');
        }
    }
    console.log('hey!');
```

won't work and results in infinite recursion.

Comment: http://tobyho.com/2012/07/27/taking-over-console-log/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy, just save a reference to the (original) console before overwriting it:

```
var originalConsole = window.console;
console = {
    log: function(message) {
        originalConsole.log(message);
        // do whatever custom thing you want
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course! That is nifty. Unfortunately it's ultimately the same as defining a custom debug service, as the line number/file reported is still that of the single root originalConsole.log(message); call, rather than the line number of the caller like console.log();. I'm looking for some way to interact with the Web Console as console.log() does, although it's possible it doesn't exist.

Comment: Check out http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API.  That link is specifically for Firebug, but it should give you a decent idea of what is/isn't possible when working with the console object.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
var colors = {
  DEFAULT: '\033[m',
  RED: '\033[31m',
  GREEN: '\033[32m',
  BLUE: '\033[34m'
};
var print = {
  out: function(message) {
    console.log(message);
  },
  read: function(message) {
    prompt(message + ' ');
  },
  color: function(message, color) {
    if (color == 'RED') {
      console.log(`${colors.RED}${message}${colors.DEFAULT}`);
    }
    else if (color == 'GREEN') {
      console.log(`${colors.GREEN}${message}${colors.DEFAULT}`);
    }
    else if (color == 'BLUE') {
      console.log(`${colors.BLUE}${message}${colors.DEFAULT}`);
    }
    else {
      console.log(`${colors.RED}ValueError: \"${color}\" is not in the colors set.`);
    }
  }
};
```

You can test it using:

```
print.out('Hello World!');
print.read('Hello World!');
print.color('Hello World!', 'RED');
print.color('Hello World!', 'GREEN');
print.color('Hello World!', 'BLUE');
```